# Wifi not working on Asus vivobook S14, but Kubuntu can see it temporarily

Tags: wireless, kubuntu

I just got an Asus vivobook S14, which came with Endless OS linux. I soon found out that Endless is extremely limited - I can't install any of the applications I could in windows or mint. Only what is strictly built for Endless OS, basically.
However, booting from usb, none of these: ubuntu 18.5, mint 18.3 cinnamon and kde, or debian 9.4.0, can even see the available wifi networks. Strangely, Kubuntu 18.04 (still booting from usb) can see my network at first, then I type the password, then it tries to connect but fails, and then it disappears, it cannot see it anymore, except if I boot again. So, Kubuntu got the closest (besides looking so nice!).
This laptop has to ethernet port.
I am flexible - if anyone knows about ANY linux distro that easily connects here, and that is fairly normal (meaning I can install .deb stuff for example), I'm interested. 
Or any other solution. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks, guys :)

---

Requested command and output:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: r8822be
Kernel modules: r8822be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Endless uses flatpak like any other modern distro, most applications should work except for applications like texlive. https://flathub.org/home

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I was frustrated after trying so many times. I'm sure flatpak is a great new fancy thing and people are working hard on it. But it just doesn't have the stuff I need yet... Qgis, Rstudio, wine... possible more =/