# Wifi realtek r8822be not working - ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.15.0-20

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, realtek-wireless

The laptop is an Asus Vivobook S14, and it came with Endless OS linux, but I need to install ubuntu (or some other distro) because many of the applications I need are not yet available in flatpak.
It seems also that Endless does not easily allow for dual boot, so for now I'm testing kubuntu 18.04 on live booting. I have run updates, but since it's live I cannot really do fancy changes. I'm trying to avoid wiping out Endless until I'm sure the wifi will work.
I got a Plugable ethernet usb adaptor, because this laptop has no port. It worked out of the box for linux.
Secure boot is disabled.
The file rtl8822befw.bin came already in `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi`.

`sudo lspci -v` returns this about the wifi:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822 (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
    !!! Unknown header type 7f
    Kernel driver in use: r8822be
    Kernel modules: r8822be
```

Wireless info script output below.

Any directions, tips or solutions? Any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you!

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 29 Jun 2018 08:42 UTC +0000

Booted last: 29 Jun 2018 00:00 UTC +0000

Script from: 10 Jan 2018 20:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: file=/cdrom/preseed/kubuntu.seed, cdrom-detect/try-usb=true, noprompt, floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0, ignore_uuid, boot=casper, maybe-ubiquity, quiet, splash, ---

##### desktop ###########################

Plasma

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
Device [10ec:b822] (rev ff)
Kernel driver in use: r8822be
Kernel modules: r8822be

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3526 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a07 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0930:6545 Toshiba Corp. Kingston DataTraveler 
102/2.0 / HEMA Flash Drive 2 GB / PNY Attache 4GB Stick
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211              778240  1 r8822be
cfg80211              622592  2 mac80211,r8822be
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
wmi                    24576  2 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  40960  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback <MAC address> brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
4: enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
inet 192.168.111.106/24 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
   valid_lft 3682sec preferred_lft 3682sec
inet6 fe80::3149:6392:52e:60ca/64 scope link noprefixroute 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
      Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.111.1 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.111.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> proto kernel scope link 
src 192.168.111.106 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search okologia.mta.local

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

NetworkManager

Running:

root      1179     1  0 07:51 ?        00:00:01 
/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         ASIX Elec. Corp.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        AX88179
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ax88179_178a
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>' 
[IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/net/enx<IF from 
MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       166ac9ed-5e26-34f0-878b-            
1834a8a1cc49
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                           
/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     1000 Mb/s
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.111.106/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.111.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh =     
192.168.111.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.111.0/24, nh =     
0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 
0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.111.56
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          okologia.mta.local
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        domain_name =     
okologia.mta.local
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        network_number = 192.168.111.0
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                            
requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       expiry = 1530265438
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       broadcast_address = 
192.168.111.255
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       routers = 192.168.111.1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 4729
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 
192.168.111.56
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                           
requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 
192.168.111.23
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       ip_address = 192.168.111.106
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::3149:6392:52e:60ca/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 
256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 
256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 
100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS:     
/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   166ac9ed-5e26-34f0-878b- 
1834a8a1cc49 | Wired connection 1

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp2s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceWifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express     
Root Port
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8822be
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 4.15.0-20-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               N/A
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlp2s0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/net/wlp2s0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.2GHZ:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.5GHZ:                   yes
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

SSID  BSSID  MODE  CHAN  FREQ  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY  ACTIVE  IN-USE 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Etc/UTC (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, NO-IR
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlp2s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz    
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz    
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz    
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz    
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.    

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlp2s0    Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-        
generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     1CEA5CF286EDB289C1D0BF8
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is 
supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before 
disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before 
disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we 
decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe 
response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control 
algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-20-        
generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     D5B0789D4C423C81CCFB437
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.15.0-20-generic SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries 
(per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code 
(charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs 
/sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  952.325528] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: unregister 
'ax88179_178a' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit 
Ethernet
[  952.325641] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: Failed to 
read reg index 0x0002: -19
[  952.325650] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: Failed to 
write reg index 0x0002: -19
[  952.372581] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> 
(unregistered): 
 Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[  952.372591] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> 
(unregistered): 
Failed to write reg index 0x0001: -19
[  952.372597] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]> 
(unregistered): 
Failed to write reg index 0x0002: -19
[ 2019.096254] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 eth0: register 'ax88179_178a' at 
usb- 
0000:00:14.0-1, ASIX AX88179 USB 3.0 Gigabit Ethernet, <MAC 'enx<IF 
from MAC [IF2]>' [IF2]>
[ 2019.110970] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: renamed 
from eth0
[ 2019.155672] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: link 
is not ready (repeated 2 times)
[ 2021.871159] ax88179_178a 2-1:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: ax88179 - 
Link status is: 1
[ 2021.877863] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enx<IF from MAC [IF2]>: 
link 
becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Just to let you know, the older post https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045084/wifi-not-working-on-asus-vivobook-s14-but-kubuntu-can-see-it-temporarily?noredirect=1#comment1704314_1045084 is a replicate to this one - the account was changed, and there was less info there. Sorry for that. Please any one who has permission feel free to delete the old one or mark it as replicate.

Comment: This is a solution to another realtek wifi driver, but maybe can help: https://sovietek.wordpress.com/2018/06/09/a-possible-solution-for-the-hp-laptops-weak-wifi-issue-when-using-linux/

Comment: I am suspicious that this: `Device b822 (rev ff) (prog-if ff) !!! Unknown header type 7f` suggests that the device is defective.

Comment: Defective? But it works perfectly on Endless OS, @chili555...

Comment: With the ethernet detached, restart Network Manager: `sudo service network-manager restart` Does NM see networks to select from? What is the result of the terminal command: `dmesg | grep -e 8822 -e wlp` As the result may be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: The network-manager restart returned nothing at all. Here is the output: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/52cFsxdWbC/ . But actually, since yesterday it started acting out on Endless also. So perhaps you were right before, @chili555

Comment: Almost every entry in your paste is error, ERR or failed. I still suspect that the hardware is failed. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me (after rebooting)

```
echo "options r8822be aspm=0"  | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/r8822be.conf
```

My vivobook S14 came with Windows though.. not sure if that matters.

Kudos to the guys over on this thread:
http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=2026375&p=3

Comment: It worked for me too, after also updating/upgrading. Thanks :) Finally could retire my wifi dongle.